# If field does not exist, query by a different field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection where some documents have an `InstallDate` field, and some do not. However, all documents will have `LastPublishedDate`.

I need to query this collection by `InstallDate` if that field exists. If it doesn't exist, then I need to query it by `LastPublishedDate` instead.

Here is what I tried, however `$cond` cannot be used as a top-level operator.

```
Patch.countDocuments({
    $and: [
        {OrgId: orgId},
        {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    InstallDate: { $exists: true }
                },
                then: {
                    InstallDate: { $gt: startTime, $lt: endTime }
                },
                else: {
                    LastPublishedDate: { $gt: startTime, $lt: endTime }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
})
```

Comment: Does it throw an error if you query using both and the `InstallDate` does not exist?

Comment: @Jarvis You mean something like `{OrgId: orgId, LastPublishedDate: { $gt: startTime, $lt: endTime }, InstallDate: { $gt: startTime, $lt: endTime }}`? It does not throw an error but that does not yield the results I want. Doing that returns only documents that have both fields between the timeframe. I only want to query by one field or the other, not both at once.

Comment: Ah... that make sense. Hrm... Have you thought of using a Query Builder? Almost all the way down this page: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html it mentions using a query builder instead of JSON which would allow you to use standard JavaScript if/else constructs.

Comment: @Jarvis I don't see any kind of `if` statement in there. It looks like the Mongoose query builder is just syntax sugar for regular MQL queries. I'd rather do this all in a one-shot query, but it's looking more and more like I'll have to do several queries with custom logic on the application side. My only concern is that with the huge number of records this collection will have in it, it may case memory-limit issues.

Comment: You have to put in the if statement... it does not run the query until the `.exec()` statement. The whole point of a query builder is to surround bits of it in logic or build a base query to be passed into other functions to add onto it. I didn't give you the answer, but I did point you to the exact resource you need to find the answer yourself and develop it yourself. Don't call `.exec` until you have prepared the whole query.

Comment: @Jarvis Right I get that, but that would require going to the database while I'm making the query in order to find out if the `InstallDate` field exists. How can I build the query beforehand if I haven't already gone to the DB to see if the field exists?

Comment: It would need to run that logic on each document... sounds to me like you should query based on the `LastPublishedDate` and maybe filter on the `InstallDate` for those objects that have it. Interested to see if anyone else has an answer... I feel this should be possible as this is the point of document databases...

Comment: @Jarvis Right? It sounds like such a simple thing and yet it seems like nobody online has ever asked this question. I suppose I'll just have to filter it myself with several queries then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for documents where `InstallDate` is in the correct range, or `InstallDate` does not exist and `LastPublishedDate` is in the correct range.

```
Patch.countDocuments({
  OrgId: orgId,
  $or: [
    {InstallDate: { $gt: startTime, $lt: endTime }},
    {InstallDate: { $exists: false }, LastPublishedDate: { $gt: startTime, $lt: endTime }}
  ]
})
```